# soap response with several elements - how to filter?

Tags: javascript, crm

I executed a soap request (using XrmServiceToolkit for CRM 2015) and I can get the response doing:

```
var buid = resultXml.getElementsByTagName("a:Results")[0].childNodes[0].childNodes[1].text;
```

However this "buid" variable gives me a couple of elements "subject" and "description" all together. Console shows something like:

```
subjectTHISISTHESUBJETdescription<p><font size=2>THISISMYDESCRIPTION</font></p>
```

What I really need is to store just the description in a variable. Any idea how to do it please? is an object what I get with "getElementsByTagName"? is there any method to pick up just whatever in "description"??

I would really appreciate any clue as I have been stuck with this for weeks.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

you can do more easy than going by the dom on the object.

like something like this
                if (resultXML.length > 0)
                {
                    if(typeof resultXML[0].attributes.description != "undefined")
                    {
                        var description = resultXml[0].attributes.description.value;
                    }
                }

You can use the debug on the IE for example to put a break point and add a watch on the object or expand the object to get the result you want.

Cheers,
Jorge Cunha

Comment: Hi Jorge, thanks for your time. I am afraid it does not work as resultXml returns an empty object. So doing what you suggested I got: "Unable to get property 'attributes' of undefined or null reference"

Comment: and even if it's an empty object, I can display the result throught the console using ".text"  . I don't really understand what is the response ? and object? an array?

Comment: You need to do the verification to see if exist                            if (resultXML.length > 0)
    {
     if(typeof resultXML[0].attributes.description != "undefined")
     {
      var description = resultXml[0].attributes.description.value;
     }
    }

Comment: Sorry for being that insistent Jorge but it's driving me nuts. To summarize I've got:         var buid = resultXml.getElementsByTagName("a:Results")[0].childNodes[0].childNodes[1];       and the result of this    console.log(buid);  // [object] { }
console.log(buid.text);   //subjectTHISISTHESUBJETdescription<p><font size=2>THISISMYDESCRIPTION</font></p>

Comment: why is "buid" and empty object?? that is why I cant work with attributes....then how can I work with "buid.text" which has the "description" that I want :/

Comment: Did you try my code, I am 99% this going to give you the description of your call from the XRMTOOLKIT? For example if you resultXML is empty your not going to have any result for example. And using ChildNodes whit the index hard code you are going maybe have always different result depending of your result of the resultXML. Try to debug and see where you are having the issue.